# Uploading Products through CSV excel sheet - Site loading very slow

Tags: extensions, performance, importexport, server

we bought magento extension for uploading the products through excel sheet.

we are uploading Products using csv file.

But when we are uploading the csv file , its taking more time to upload.

At the time of uploading, site will load very slowly and backend will not open

Is it the problem with the extension or with the server.

What steps we need to take solve these issues

After a quick search in google

1)we did Truncating log tables

2)Delete not required attributes

3)change Index Mode to Manual update

4) increased server requirements :

```
OS: Ubuntu Server Edition 
Server: Apache
RAM: 16GB
Hard Disk: 160 GB SSD
```

what else we need to do to speed up the uploading.

please give me some tips to speed up. because we are struggling a lot for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the use of the MAGMI importer

[Magmi Importer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

if used properly is the fastest method I know to import products in magento

Comment: fine, but for some  reason we have to use the extension.

Comment: In this case I suggest to optimize first the mySQL configuration files specifically for magento, you will find a lot of articles on google.

Comment: than i will try that.....